# view controllers in swift

Tags: swift, interface-builder

i cant figure out how to use a second view controller to change or add/remove something from my first view controller

i have a variable in my second view controller that lets me access all my variables in my first view controller

```
var players = ViewController()
addOne3.addTarget(self, action: "player:", forControlEvents:     UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
view.addSubview(changeButton)

func player(sender: UIButton){

    players.addOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

}
```

and i have a function that uses one of my buttons in the second view controller to change the color of another button in the first view controller but nothing changes to the button i am trying to change

Comment: You need to get a reference to the right instance of your first view controller. The code you've shown creates an entirely new instance of ViewController (via ()) and then modifies it. When you go back to your first view controller, you never see the changes because that instance of the ViewController class was never modified.

Comment: how do i do go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a protocol in the secondVC and add that delegate in the FirstVC. And add the functions or values which you want in the FirstVC. When you click in the button which in the SecondVC, the function value will change because  of the protocol effect. Then you can do the colour changing thing.

```
import UIKit

protocol CustomProtocol
{
    func getValueFromButton( isitTrue : Bool)
}


class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate : CustomProtocol?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func buttonsf(sender: UIButton)
    {
        delegate?.getValueFromButton(true)
    }
}
```

import UIKit

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, CustomProtocol {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func getValueFromButton( isitTrue : Bool)
    {
        if isitTrue
        {
            // do this
        }

        else
        {
            // do that
        }
    }
    @IBAction func buttonsf(sender: UIButton)
    {
        var SecondVCObject : SecondViewCOntroller =  SecondViewCOntroller()
        SecondVCObject.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: SecondVCObject.delegate = self this line gives me the error: Variable 'SecondVCObject' used before being initialized